# My camera is not supported/detected

Tags: camera

I followed a guide on youtube to set up my raspberry pi. I'm trying to use python for facial recognition but the camera is not working.

I did

```
vcgencmd get_camera
```

in the terminal but the result was

```
supported=0 detected=0
```

Does anyone have any idea why supported shows 0?

Comment: maybe the camera is not supported ... or it is not connected ... or it is defective ... or etc. etc.

Comment: `supported=0` means you haven't enabled camera at all - note: you hopefully are running buster, not bullseye

Comment: @Bravo how do i check if im running buster or bullseye? and if im running bullseye, how do i change it to buster?

Comment: `lsb_release -a` - go back to buster by downloading and flash buster image

Comment: @Bravo sorry im still new to this but where can i download this and how do i flash the buster image? do u know any tutorials or guides i can follow?

Comment: you download it from raspberry pi site - https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/ - , and flash it just like any other image

Comment: let me make that clearer ... [buster lite - no GUI](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_lite_armhf/images/raspios_lite_armhf-2021-05-28/) and [buster regular - with GUI](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_armhf/images/raspios_armhf-2021-05-28/) - as far as flashing the image - what did you use this time

Comment: @Bravo i dont know what i used but basically i downloaded Raspberry Pi Imager v1.6.2 on my desktop, and then wrote the Raspberry Pi OS (32-bit) into the SD Card and then followed the terminal commands at the bottom of the page [link](https://core-electronics.com.au/tutorials/face-identify-raspberry-pi.html)

Comment: @Bravo whats the difference between with GUI and no GUI

Comment: desktop or cli only - whatever you used for your current image ... lite or not lite

Comment: @Bravo Thanks for the confirmation on bullseye.  I've been pulling my hair out on this release for the camera in my pi zero.  Flashing back to buster.  Thanks.

Comment: @jwbradley - i wouldn't be so quick to trust a year old comment :p

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the new Raspberry Pi OS, the camera interface is disabled.
The workaround is to open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and type `sudo raspi-config`, go to **Interface Options** and then **Legacy Camera** and reboot. These camera interfaces are deprecated and will not be supported going forwards. So use with caution and check for updates.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Check first if the camera is supported](http://elinux.org/RPi_VerifiedPeripherals#USB_Webcams)

2. Try a powered USB hub to plug in the camera / maybe it isnt getting enough power

Then you can install this tool to test out the camera`sudo apt-get install luvcview`

Comment: its a raspberry pi camera that came with the raspberry pi itself

Comment: what makes you think this is a USB camera?

Answer (score 0):

I used the libcamera-still command and it worked in the morning
Then i installed dlib
After that the same command showed the error "no cameras available"
I could access camera through raspcontroller...but not through camera legacy. I could access it through camera (usb)
Then i tried
sudo apt-get install fswebcam
fswebcam image.jpg
...and bingo ! It worked.

Answer (score 0):

Using the latest Raspberry Pi OS, bookworm, my Pi Zero W v1.1 reports the camera is missing with the following:

```
~ $ vcgencmd get_camera
supported=0 detected=0, libcamera interfaces=0
```

However, I can see it is connected by running:

```
~ $ libcamera-still --list-cameras
Available cameras
-----------------
0 : ov5647 [2592x1944 10-bit GBRG] (/base/soc/i2c0mux/i2c@1/ov5647@36)
    Modes: 'SGBRG10_CSI2P' : 640x480 [58.92 fps - (16, 0)/2560x1920 crop]
                             1296x972 [43.25 fps - (0, 0)/2592x1944 crop]
                             1920x1080 [30.62 fps - (348, 434)/1928x1080 crop]
                             2592x1944 [15.63 fps - (0, 0)/2592x1944 crop]
```

And I can take pictures without issue:

```
libcamera-still -o snap.jpg
```